# Proving a theorem of ODE- Picard's iteration theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

In this problem, I am confused how to begin with and what theorems to use in order to prove this statement. Should I use Picard's iteration theorem to solve this as we are being provided with y(t) and y_n+1(t).

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Picard iteration (the full machinery) is not completely necessary, this proof only uses basic triangle inequality on the terms that you have. And you have a Lipschitz-like condition to prove the second inequality.

Comment: can u pls help me out in this? I dont understand how to proceed this.

Comment: I am helping you out, I gave you hints. Did you start plugging things in, at least for the first inequality? What is $y_1$, etc? What happens when you plug it into the absolute value with $y_0$? What did I mean by triangle inequality? I am not doing the problem for you like last time where you didn't read my answer before asking questions.

Comment: I got this man, thanks a lot for your help. However, I need help in part (c) of this Q7. I have posted a separate question for this.